# Comparing numbers in inline c assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to get a feel for inline assembly in c, and I have never done any assembly programming before, so I'm trying to convert random pieces of code I have to assembly.
I got a problem with the code below, what I wanted it to do was returning 0x20 (32) if a is below
0x20 (32) or above 0x7e (126). (thats unprintable characters) However it also turns the characters
between those numbers into 0x20 (32)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo(int a) {
  asm (
    "mov $0x20, %%ebx;"
    "cmp %%eax, %%ebx;"
    "jl l1;"
    "mov $0x7e, %%ebx;"
    "cmp %%eax, %%ebx;"
    "jg l1;"
    "jmp l2;"
    "l1: movl $0x20, %%eax;"
    "l2:;"

    : "=a" (a)
    : "a" (a)
    : "%ebx"
  );
  return a;
}
int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
    printf("%i: %i\n", i, foo(i));
  }
}
```

This outputs
0: 32
1: 32
2: 32
...
31: 32
32: 32
33: 32
34: 32
35: 32
...
125: 32
126: 32
127: 32
128: 32
...

Comment: whats the contents of %%eax at start of function

Comment: surely it should be 42 not 32 :-)

Comment: @amdixon It is `a`, as said in `: "a" (a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are quite close. Maybe [this HOWTO](http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) can help you.

Essentially, you have the logic wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo(int a) {
  asm(
    "mov $0x20, %%edx\n\t" // I use %edx because it optimizes better.
    "cmp %1, %%edx\n\t"    // I use %1 because that's more flexible.
    "jg l1\n\t"            // jg here, not jl!
    "mov $0x7e, %%edx\n\t"
    "cmp %1, %%edx\n\t"
    "jl l1\n\t"            // jl here, not jg!
    "jmp l2\n\t"
    "l1: movl $0x20, %0\n\t" // move the result to 0
    "l2:\n\t"

    : "=a" (a) // output
    : "0" (a) // input is the same
    : "%edx" // what is clobbered
  );
  return a;
}
int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
    printf("%i: %i\n", i, foo(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems I just messed up jl and jg, my version works if they're switched.

Answer (score 1):

The code will returns 32 since you didn't specify *else*:

```
  ...
  asm (
    "mov $0x20, %%ebx;"
    "cmp %%eax, %%ebx;" // the order should be ebx, eax
    "jl l1;"
    "mov $0x7e, %%ebx;"
    "cmp %%eax, %%ebx;" // the order should be ebx, eax
    "jg l1;"
                        // missing step here
    "jmp l2;"
    "l1: movl $0x20, %%eax;"
    "l2:;"
  ...
```

you can't tell the compiler where the variable `a` is going to be stored, you just passed `a` to `asm`. You can fix it as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo(int a) {
  asm (
    "cmp $0x20, %%eax;"
    "jl l1;"
    "cmp $0x7e, %%eax;"
    "jg l1;"
    "movl $0, %%eax;"   // what should a be otherwise? 0?
    "jmp l2;"
    "l1: movl $0x20, %%eax;"
    "l2:;"

    : "=a" (a)
    : "a" (a)
    : "%ebx"
  );
  return a;
}
int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
    printf("%i: %i\n", i, foo(i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo(int a) {
  asm (
    "cmp  $0x20, %0;"  // %0 => a
    "jl   l1;"
    "cmp  $0x7e, %0;"  // %0 => a
    "jg   l1;"
    "movl $0, %1;"     // what should a be otherwise? 0?
    "jmp  l2;"
    "l1:"
    "movl $0x20, %0;"  // %0 = a = 0x20
    "l2:;"
    : "=r" (a) // use r(egister)
    : "r" (a)
    :
  );
  return a;
}
int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
    printf("%i: %i\n", i, foo(i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The input and output definitions `"a"` resp. `"=a"` refer to `%eax`. So that was ok (but not very neat).

Comment: And: There is no need for an else. The value in `%eax` is already present.

Comment: @glglgl That depends of what he want `a` to be if it's not less than 30 or greater than 127.